# I'm not able to login with the script

Tags: python, json, scrapy, form-data, payload

I'm not able to login with the script.
Go to https://www.amscan.com, look for "Shop Now" and then "Log In".
I'm using both **FormRequest** and **Request** but the error coming is HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed. Ignoring Response [400]
Below is my code and let me know if anyone helps me.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.shell import inspect_response
import json
import re

class Amscan(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'amscan'
    start_urls = ['https://www.amscan.com/']


    def parse(self, response):
        url = 'https://b2b.amscan.com/auth/login'
        payload="{'login':{'mode':'email','username':'info@soaringfinancial.com','password':'PassSoaring$123'},'redirect':'#!/'}"
        headers = {
                  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36',
                  'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
                  'authority': 'b2b.amscan.com',
                  'sec-ch-ua': '"Google Chrome";v="87", " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="87"',
                  'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
                  'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
                  'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
                  'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
                  'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
                  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
                 }
        formdata ={
        'login': {
                'mode': "email",
                'password': my_password,
                'username': my_username,
                },
        'redirect': "#!/",
        }
        yield scrapy.FormRequest(url, formdata=formdata, headers=headers, method='POST', callback=self.login)

    def login(self, response):
        inspect_response(response, self)
```

error is...

```
2021-01-09 16:33:26 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.amscan.com/> (referer: None)
2021-01-09 16:33:27 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (400) <POST https://b2b.amscan.com/auth/login> (referer: https://www.amscan.com/)
2021-01-09 16:33:27 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <400 https://b2b.amscan.com/auth/login>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2021-01-09 16:33:27 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2021-01-09 16:33:27 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 920,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/POST': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 12975,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/400': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 4.394109,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 9, 11, 3, 27, 909495),
 'httperror/response_ignored_count': 1,
 'httperror/response_ignored_status_count/400': 1,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 2,
 'log_count/INFO': 11,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 9, 11, 3, 23, 515386)}
```

Answer (score 1):

here's some [curl2scrapy](https://michael-shub.github.io/curl2scrapy/) results for your request Try it in scrapy shell. Looks like you've missed csrf stuff and got 404'd for it.

```
from scrapy import Request

url = 'https://b2b.amscan.com/auth/login'

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:84.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/84.0",
    "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    "X-XSRF-TOKEN": "qLEN9AAM-XFCR1rAsQQ0L5lHglyxw_pNpWYg",
    "Origin": "https://b2b.amscan.com",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Referer": "https://b2b.amscan.com/",
    "TE": "Trailers"
}

cookies = {
    "_csrf": "NApyTe0Bsv6WcTyxKs_qcF8F",
    "XSRF-TOKEN": "qLEN9AAM-XFCR1rAsQQ0L5lHglyxw_pNpWYg",
    "client_sid": "s%3AIkCcqv7GeKTLHwc9NaV2eWFV8EqEJXg0.jbE9Hfl0uobLScUfJk8muPteqxSEK0smQsZx2wkFn6Y"
}

body = '{"login":{"mode":"email","username":"ololo@trololo.com","password":"ololo"},"redirect":"#!/"}'

request = Request(
    url=url,
    method='POST',
    dont_filter=True,
    cookies=cookies,
    headers=headers,
    body=body,
)

fetch(request)
```

Comment: After login the website when I click Ship Now > Juvenile > Licensed Show XHR Request and click on Search 'b2b.amscan.com/search' 
I showed XSRF-TOKEN was changed. so I'm not getting a response.
is there any XSRF-TOKEN auto-generate(unique-way)?
because after login when I click on a category Xsrf token changed always.
If I log in using my credential and cookie after if I log out then going for category search as upper I mentioned.
after the for that search URL 'https://b2b.amscan.com/search' response showing `{"success":false,"message":"Could not find User/Account Details"}`

Comment: you should go to the page first, read csrf token and use it in your request construction as mentioned above.
And of course you should use you real login password credentials.

Comment: But the x-xsrf-token changed after some time and not giving me to response true.

Comment: you can get csrf values via cookies here: make get request to https://b2b.amscan.com/, csrf will be in response headers set-cookie